# Swipe fragment rather than filling the entire screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen, swipe, navigation-drawer

I want my application contain a side fragment like NavigationDrawer , but i dont want it to be a list view , I want to design it like i do to every fragment/activity in my app.

In other words I would like fragment that opens from the side rather than filling the entire screen just like NavigationDrawer.

Possible to do this?

Comment: [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) example uses ListView, instead you can use one more FrameLayout
 & push fragment to it.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that if I use fragment instead listview then I get the result I was looking for?
But then I will not have all the preparations as they do to listview with adapters etc.
Am i right?